# Nodejs: validate if email already exists in the database when registering user

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've tried some methods but nothing works
and I'm trying to change

Anyone can give me a little trick to create this function in node js?

Your suggestions will be very helpful for me to solve it

```js
//router_register.js
// Definisikan router dari express
const router = require('express').Router();
// Ambil index.js dari controller dan panggil variabel didalamnya
const registerController = require('../controllers').register;
// Definisikan middleware verify.js
const verifyUser = require('../configs/verify');

// Rute 'http://localhost:5050/register/' digunakan untuk menampilkan form register
router.get('/', verifyUser.isLogout, registerController.formRegister);
// Rute 'http://localhost:5050/register/save' digunakan untuk menyimpan data yang diinput user saat register
router.post('/save', verifyUser.isLogout, registerController.saveRegister);

// Export agar dapat dibaca oleh express
module.exports = router;
```

```js
//controller_register
const config = require('../configs/database');
let mysql = require('mysql');
let pool = mysql.createPool(config);

pool.on('error', (err)=> {
  console.error(err);
});

module.exports = {
  formRegister(req, res) {
    res.render("login", {
      // Definisikan semua varibel yang ingin ikut dirender kedalam register.ejs
      url: 'http://localhost:5050/',
    });
  },
  saveRegister(req, res) {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.pass;

    if (username && email && password) {
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(
          `INSERT INTO table_user (user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?,?,SHA2(?,512)); `, [username, email, password], function (error, results) {
            if (error) throw error;
            req.flash('color', 'success');
            req.flash('status', 'Yes..');
            req.flash('message', 'Registrasi berhasil');
            res.redirect('/login');
          });
        connection.release();
      })
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
      res.end();
    }
  }
}
```

And please tell me which parts I should fix to make it even better for this coding

Comment: Please start with a clear explanation of your problem. "I want x, but I get y". Was there an error code? That would be useful. Then continue with "I tried z, but got w."  Tell us at least where your code failed. With what you have posted, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: Asking for a ready code is generally discouraged. As @Jerry pointed out, it's better to try the implementation yourself, then post the code and ask a specific question about the error you run into. That said, since you already have some working code, I will suggest a general approach you can try in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. May be even both to get a robust solution. As you asked for general direction, instead of giving you exact code, I will try to point you in right direction.

1. In your `saveRegister` function, before you run `INSERT`, using email, you can run another query to fetch any existing user's with the incoming email address. If you find one, throw an exception for user trying to register with existing email.
2. To make this even better, you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint on your table in the database for the `user_email` column. This way if you do try to save another user with a duplicate email, you should get an exception that your try block will catch.

All the best. Please update the question with specifics if you try this approach and still need more help.